# PHP script throwing internal server error 500, fixed when turning on display_errors

Tags: php

I came across an issue today, that my PHP script would send a server error 500 upon finishing (on apache). The code was something like:

```
//many stuff here that work
echo "It reached here";
exit;
```

and I was always reaching the point before the exit; command. Doing a google search, I came across [this post](http://www.infotales.com/php-script-throwing-internal-server-error-500/), which suggested turning on display_errors. I did it and the 500 error went away.

So I wanted to ask, does anyone have an explanation on why this happens? This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184001/weird-500-internal-server-error-firebug-php-display-errors-ajax) describes a similar case, but there are no explanations.

As always, thanks in advance

Comment: If you put `exit(1)`, the error is perfectly normal, but by default, the code should be `1` which means "Successful termination"... Could you try forcing the success by explicitly specifying the `0` ? `exit(0)`

Comment: I did that but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the code generated a parse error inside an eval() function in a loop. This kind of error does not break code execution but does produce a 500 error

Comment: This does sound like a PHP bug.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty likely you get a 500 status code as well, but because PHP echoes something to the browser apache won't jump in and display it's standard status 500 error page.

You would need to verify the actual status code to verify that you won't still get a 500 error.

In case of a fatal error, PHP normally sends a 500 status code. As often the process has failed at that time (hence causing the fatal) and sometime no output is generated since then, the webserver jumps in and gives the user the standard 500-internal-server-error-page.

Comment: I understand that, but where would the fatal error occur? I do get a 500 status code btw.

Comment: You need to look into the error message to learn more about the fatal error and where it occurs. You should add the error message in full to your question (you can shorten the file-path).

Comment: There is no error message. I just receive a status code 500 with "Internal server error" on my browser, along with the page (which is an otherwise normal ajax response)

Comment: @periklis: Time that you start with error logging, that means PHP writes each error that happens to a file - the error log. Configure PHP to log errors, then provoke the 500 error and look into the error log of PHP. You will see the message then. If you opt for displaying the errors, you will see the error within the browser (not recommended for production environments but sometimes ok when developing). The holy grail is using a remote debugger, but that's probably too much for the moment.

Comment: I assure you that I'm quite competent with error logging. The problem is - php does not appear to produce any errors at all for the lifecycle of the script

Comment: Are you really sure this ain't a PHP error? If so, then check the error log of your webserver. That's the next place to look into.

Comment: unfortunately the webserver error log does not contain any helpful information. Only the access log reports that the request returned a status code of 500. Anyway, I guess I should work with our admins to figure out whether this is a php or apache error. Thanks for the help, I'll post back here if there's any news

Comment: If you see a 500 error in the access log, there's also a report in the error log. If not, it's a PHP error. So looks like you're guessing. But trouble-shooting is best done not with guessing but with facts. So please switch your brain on, concentrate on facts, terminate any assumptions and go to straight real-life now.

Comment: ok, disregarding your offensive tone, you where right in the first place that this was a php error after all and I did have to have a closer look to the code. It appears that the code generated a parse error inside an eval() function in a loop. This kind of error does not break code execution but does produce a 500 error

Comment: If PHP simply stops - crashes, seg faults, whatever - then apache will send the 500 error. PHP does not get to log any details of the error that crashed it, because it crashed. Having this problem myself - something in WP is causing PHP to end, and nothing is being logged beyond apache sending the browser a 500 error because PHP went tits-up. A stack trace could probably be found or turned on, but analysing that will be a major task in itself.

Comment: @Jason: It depends, check php error logging and then the SAPI. Some SAPI do actually write into the error log of the webserver. Some do not and then you can find details in the php error log (if you have logging enabled). Additionally for quick debugging, you can enable display errors (normally only suitable for development environments).